# SolrCloud Deduplication Overwrite isn't working

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I've been struggling to get Deduplication to work in SolrCloud (version 8.6).  My solrconfig.xml contains:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="dedupeOn">
       <processor class="solr.processor.SignatureUpdateProcessorFactory">
         <bool name="enabled">true</bool>
         <str name="signatureField">dedupeId</str>
         <bool name="overwriteDupes">true</bool>
         <str name="fields">journal_doi,internal_pmid</str>
         <str name="signatureClass">solr.processor.Lookup3Signature</str>
       </processor>
       <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
       <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
       <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
     </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

and

```
 <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" >
  <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="update.chain">dedupeOn</str>
  </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

my managedschema contains:

```
<field name="dedupeId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

In my test, I add 1000 documents, and commit manually.  I see the "dedupeId" is created with the hash.
I then add 10 more documents that I know are duplicates, and again commit manually.  These 10 rows are added, and the original document with the matching dedupeId is not overwritten.  For example:

```
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"maxScore":2.1554677,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "internal_pmid":"13367837",
        "dedupeId":"7f0306ecd909a68e",
        "journal_doi":"10.1097/00005053-195603000-00006"},
      {
        "internal_pmid":"13367837",
        "dedupeId":"7f0306ecd909a68e",
        "journal_doi":"10.1097/00005053-195603000-00006"}]
  }}
```

I'm not sure if its significant, but in the solr logs, I see some "add" entries that contain, in part:

```
webapp=/solr path=/update params={update.distrib=TOLEADER&update.chain=dedupeOn&distrib.from=*(shard path)*/&wt=javabin&version=2}{add=[00001hLxMb (1690871781072568320)]} 0 2
```

but other add entries do not contain the update.chain property e.g.

```
webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=javabin&version=2}{add=[00000sta0n (1690871780667817984)]} 0 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Other requests not showing `update.chain` is as expected if you have more than one node in your setup - that document was probably indexed on a different server, and the update chain ran there. The chain only runs on the first server that receives the document. Does the same thing happen if you add a document and commit after each one? (i.e. maybe the issue is that everything happens in the same commit, so when the update handler attempts to retrieve the existing document, it hasn't been committed yet)

Comment: Interesting point ... I don't think this is the case, however, since the first set of documents are committed.  The second pass contains all duplicates in the first set of documents, so they should all be visible at that point.